# A Factory building one object, is it wasteful or unnecessary?

Tags: php, oop

I used to have

```
CustomerCollection extends AbstractCollection
OrderCollection extends AbstractCollection
etc...
```

but I have realized I do not really need them and a single `Collection` will do.

I have a `CollectionFactory` that now only builds one object, a `Collection`.

I feel like it is wasteful and unnecessary but I do like using the factory because it keeps the "new" operator out of my code except for in my factories which is good and also keeps the job of object creation in my factories which is good.

Do you think it is good or bad to have a factory creating only one object?

Comment: This question can lead to open-ended discussion. Questions that have something like: `what do you think about X?` never fit Q/A format. On-topic: I see nothing wrong with your approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I have/had the same dilemma, but it is in fact in a lot of cases very useful.

I use the mapper pattern, which has dependencies on the hydrator and entity (for me). I used a default hydrator. But I changed the design and needed an other hydrator.

I could just switch the hydrator in the factory and everything was fine (just needed to code the hydrator but that was out of the scope :P )

So instead of changing all the lines of code I just needed to change one and it worked again, and did not look in files for hidden inisation because everything went through the factory.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with a factory that produces only one object. That object is instantiated in only one place and if, for example, you change the constructor arguments you have only one call to modify instead of trawling through your code for every instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases a factory may be useful, if a class has logic about how to create an instance, but you want to have some control over what instances it creates: making it create mocks in a unit test is a common use case.

In the particular case of a collection factory I suspect it's less useful. Just call new inside the class. It's easier. If you are writing very generic library code you may want to abstract over the type of collection being created, but from the class names you gave in the question it doesn't sound like that.

Of course this is quite generic advice because I don't know your code. You are best placed to determine that, but I hope this helps a little.